# Kivy garden invalid syntax error

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I just recently learned about kivy-garden and it looks great but i'm having an issue installing "flowers" into the garden. I get an error that I can't find a fix to. My bet is that it's because there's a space in my username but that's really all I can think of.

```
C:\Users\Karate Klub>garden install mapview

C:\Users\Karate Klub>python.exe C:\Users\Karate Klub\AppData\L
ocal\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\garden install mapview
  File "C:\Users\Karate", line 1
    ------------------------------------start-----------------------------------
-

^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

C:\Users\Karate Klub>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows you have to do this manually with:

```
python """C:\Users\Karate Klub\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\garden""" install mapview
```

or you can go to the directory `C:\Users\Karate Klub\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts` then run `python garden install mapview`

Comment: The first command gave me a new error but going to the directory and running python garden install mapview worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Baxorr Sorry you know In python there is no difference between the single and double quote, I confuse